# Manualy install ".nupkg" packages on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, package, nuget

I have a pre-released version of SQLite package I downloaded earlier, and I am trying to install it from Package Manager Console, I used

> install-package -includeprerelease -Source E:\e

but no success, any tips will be helpful.

edit:
the error message I encountered is:

```
install-package : Unable to find package 'a'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package -includeprerelease -Source E:\e
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

and it occurred after an error in the value entered after this request:

```
cmdlet Install-Package at command pipeline position 1 
Supply values for the following parameters:
Id:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the package id in the original command. From the error message it looks like you typed in 'a' for the package id.

```
install-package SQLite -includeprerelease -Source E:\e
```

Replace SQLite in the above command with the correct package id for your NuGet package.

Comment: thanks, but how would I know the Id of that package?
and would it be different if I am not using the latest version of that package?

Comment: The package id is the same for all versions. In the original question you said that you had downloaded it. I assumed that you had downloaded it to the E:\e folder since that is what you are using as a package source. If the package is in there you can see the package id from the filename (e.g. SQLite.1.2.3.4.nupkg)

Comment: That is correct, however I tried to use the file name as Id, with and without the extension, didn't work, it says "Unable to find package 'SQLite.nupkg' " ,that's why I suspected that the Id had a different meaning.

Comment: Use the package id part from the filename not the full name. The package id is the first part of the name before the version number. Taking jQuery as an example, the filename is jQuery.1.9.0.nupkg so the package id is `jQuery`